# Ubuntu font catalog

Tags: fonts

I am looking for a comprehensive catalog of all the fonts available for installation via Ubuntu packages, if possible with rendering sample.
Does it exist somewhere ?

Th reason I am asking is that listing the package names is of little help since there is not a one package - one font logic. Sometimes it's one font family, sometimes it's a random collection.

In addition, the package description often gives little useful information.

Comment: Not as far as I know. But you can of course do e.g. `apt search '^(fonts-|ttf-)'`

Comment: 1/ Install synaptic. Search for 'fonts'. Scroll down to see many hundreds of fonts available.  or 2/ find the ttf file for the font you wish to use and copy it into /user/share/fonts. You should then see it available for use in apps like LibreOffice.

Comment: Many thanks, but listing the packages names is of little help since there is not a one package - one font logic. Sometimes it's one font family, sometimes it's a random collection. In addition, the package description often gives little useful information.
Do all font packages start with `fonts` or `ttf-` ? I am pretty sure that fonts can also come with latex (and maybe other) packages.